# Redirect a Python-Sphinx generated webpage with Jinja2

Tags: jinja2, python-sphinx

My Python Sphinx restructuredtext project includes empty 1st level sections. How can I redirect users to the first subsection of the HTML output without resorting to raw Javascript?

Hi,

index.rst is as follows:

```
Title
=====

.. toctree::
   :hidden:

   foo.rst
   bar.rst
```

To avoid displaying a blank index.html page, I automatically display the 1st subsection, namely foo.html, via the following trick:

```
Title
=====

.. raw:: html

   <script type="text/javascript">
   window.location.href = "foo.html"
   </script>

.. toctree::
   :hidden:

   foo.rst
   bar.rst
```

Is it possible to apply the same behavior to all sections with Jinja in Python-Sphinx, i.e: if section body is empty and subsections exists, then fall back to 1st subsection?

Comment: I use a modified version of the Read the Docs Sphinx Theme.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [label](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#ref-role).

> If you place a label directly before a section title, you can reference to it with `:ref:[backtick]label-name[backtick]`. For example:

```
.. _my-reference-label:

Section to cross-reference
--------------------------

This is the text of the section.

It refers to the section itself, see :ref:`my-reference-label`.
```

> The `:ref:` role would then generate a link to the section, with the link title being “Section to cross-reference”. This works just as well when section and reference are in different source files.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm afraid it won't meet my need, which is to dynamically replace one page by another, with no user action.

In this case, it would be even simpler to remove the :hidden: toctree attribute, I think.

I'm not sure at all that Jinja would do the trick, since it's all about creating static pages.

Actually, defaulting to the 1st populated subsection if a section is empty would be a nice behavior for any theme.